# How can I merge DbContexts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I'm using MVC 4.

I want to use the new SimpleMembershipProvider and stuff coming with it, however I can't get it work.

I've created a sample site by the tutorials, the Login/Register works as expected. I can create custom entities too with the new EF.

The problem is that I have multiple DbContexts in my case, one for the users (UsersContext) and one for my custom entities (MyCustomDbContext).

I want to add users as fields like Owner, Member etc. so I'd need to share the UserProfile data across the context. How should I do that?

Can I force the SimpleMembershipInitializer to use my custom DbContext?

**EDIT**: I'm using Code First approach.

Comment: you want to add fields like Owner, Member. Where do you want to add this ? To the existing UserProfile table ?

Comment: Nope, I want to add Owner field to the custom entity, like         `public UserProfile Owner { get; set; }`.